# Show that triangle $ABC$ is isosceles if $\sin A=2\sin B\sin C$

Tags: trigonometry

The exercise is that $$\sin A=2\sin B\sin C$$

I need to show that $B=C$.

Then I try to use $\sin(\frac A2)=\sin B$ and $\cos(\frac A2)= \sin C$

Comment: In an equilateral triangle, $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}3$, and these values do not satisfy the equation above. Then what is the question?

Comment: Show that ABC is B=C which different from A

Comment: Do you mean "Show that triangle $ABC$ is isosceles"?

Comment: Yeah i was confused the word sorry

Comment: Because an equilateral triangle is also an isosceles triangle, an equilateral triangle should satisfy the above property (as mentioned by GoodDeeds), but this is not true. Please clarify the question. Did you instead mean sin A = 2 * (sin B) * (cos C)?

Comment: @MangSopheak Take $B=C=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $A=\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ and see how your question fails.

Comment: @Ananya I think the OP is asking to prove that if this relation is satisfied for $A+B+C=\pi$ then $B=C$, not that this equation is valid for all isoscelec triangles

Comment: @Stefan4024 But $A+B+C=\pi$ for all triangles be it isosceles, scalene or equilateral. I am not getting your statement.

Comment: @Ananya Here it is more clearly: If $A+B+C=\pi$ and $\sin A = 2 \sin B \cdot \sin C$ then prove that $B=C$

Comment: @Stefan4024 there is no difference! If $B=C $ then it should be isosceles.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Yes, but many of the users think that the relationship should be satisfied for every isoscelec triangle, which is wrong. We should prove this implication $A+B+C = \pi, \sin A = 2 \sin B \cdot \sin C \implies B=C$, instead of $A+B+C = \pi, B=C \implies \sin A = 2 \sin B \cdot \sin C$

Comment: @Stefan4024 If $B=C $ is the only possibility in both cases, then I dont see any difference..

Comment: @N.S.JOHN As noted there are lots of example of $B=C$, for which the relation is not satisfied, hence the second implication of my previous comment is not satisfied. Now let's assume there exist a $A,B,C$, such that $A+B+C = \pi$ and $\sin A = 2 \sin B \cdot \sin C$, then $B=C$, which means that the first implication is true.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN We need not to prove that it holds for every $B=C$, but instead that if it holds for some values then $B=C$

Comment: @Stefan4024 let me attempt the question to understand.

Comment: @Ananya it dosent fail when $B=C=\frac {\pi}{6}$

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Why? $R.H.S.=\frac{1}{2}$ when $B=C=\frac{\pi}{6}$ which gives $A=\frac{2\pi}{3}$, hence $L.H.S.=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ananya Yes I made a mistake sorry